# Set up AdMob mediation place

Tags: ios, admob

According to this [article](https://support.tapatalk.com/threads/setup-admob-mediation-for-your-byo-app.16533/) to setup mediation I have to create `admob` account and under and follow the instructions. I created account but can't go to "mediation.admob.com" it redirects me to login page.

How I can setup mediation placement, and get mediation ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That article is out of date.
When in doubt go to the source: http://www.google.com/ads/admob/